SF novel where humanity has developed on two paths
I am trying to identify a novel I remember reading years ago. It could well be part of a series or  something well known, but not to me! Maybe even an Asimov Foundation novel.
I remember that humanity has developed along two paths, with one having technology and maintenance almost as a regimented skill, whilst the technology of the other has been neglected and equipment fails as a consequence. I remember the use of a 'first echelon tool kit' and a first encounter when a technician adjusts an air system or similar on a neglected spaceship, after the pilot reluctantly agrees to this.

It's a novella, not a novel, but I believe you're recalling The Specter General (1952) by Theodore Cogswell.
The story takes place in two locales, one a military base of a decaying empire, and the other a relatively primitive encampment on an isolated planet where the remnants of an imperial maintenance unit are preserving the traditions - and skills - of the past.
Trying to avoid being seen in a fight, the protagonist hides in a suit of space armour that he triggers into flight.  Lost, he is picked up by a badly-maintained scout, which he proceeds to fix.  This is the scene of fixing an air system that you recall.
There is a more complete summary on Wikipedia.
The exact quote about a "first echelon kit:"

Kurt looked at it, closed his eyes, and thought for a moment. The thing did look familiar. Suddenly a picture of it popped into his mind. Page 318 in the "Manual of Auxiliary Mechanisms."
"It's fantastic!" he said.
"What is?" said the little man.
"This." Kurt pointed to the conditioner. "I didn’t know they existed in real life. I thought they were just in books. You got a first echelon kit?"
"Sure," said Ozaki. "It's in that recess by the head of the bunk. Why?"
Kurt pulled the kit out of its retaining clips and opened its cover, fishing around until he found a small screwdriver and a pair of needle-nose pliers.
"I think I'll fix it," he said conversationally.

You can read the story at the Internet Archive in Astounding, June 1952.

Brilliant. Thanks for your prompt and informative answer. You are spot on, that's the one.

Thanks so much for your time and effort.
